# Ideas for designing a Secure, "Low Cost" method for confirming client-side game results

Tags: facebook, security

This is more a system design question/challenge, than a coding question.

Basically, I'm thinking of throwing together a [Bejeweled](http://www.popcap.com/games/free/bejeweled)-esque game on Facebook using just HTML, CSS, and javascript.  This is mostly out of a desire to learn all the little caveats of FBJS via a non-trivial project.

So here's the deal.  When developing for Facebook, actual API calls are very expensive; not only is there an additional POST to the Facebook servers, there's also the api call limit and throttling to worry about.  In a nutshell, the fewer calls to Facebook the better.  Combine this with the timing concerns of even this simple puzzle game, and there's good reason to aggressively minimize the number of callbacks in general.

Not being a security expert, here's the design I've come up with:

1. Embed a random seed in the game page.
2. Use that seed to create the game board (As well as additional pieces as needed).
3. Tweak the seed (xor, concatenate and hash, something like that) after each player move, based on time since last move. Edit: I should probably also include the actual move taken in mutating the seed.
4. Upon game completion post back the following: game start time, each move taken and when, and the client side results.
5. On the server, re-run the game with the given data, sanity checking the start time and move times, and then confirm that the results match.

   To mitigate denial of service, the game itself will be tweaked to have a win by turn X condition.

   To discourage the server being used as a "oracle" of sorts, a user posting back an invalid game will be banned for some constant time X (X being on the order of minutes).

This design requires three Facebook call per game played: one to store the random seed before the game is played, one to fetch it after the game is finished, and one to update the player's score if the game is valid.

What I'm trying to proof the system against is straight up score spoofing (http://...?myscore=999999999, or similar).  I'd also like to mitigate "look ahead" attacks, wherein the user can tell what pieces are coming to the board next. Denial of service attacks on the hosting server (intentional or otherwise) should also be prevented.

The actual question, can anyone see a flaw in this design?  Equivalently, is there a simpler design that meets my criteria?

Note:  I am aware how unnecessary this probably is, but its an interesting question none the less.

---

I'm going to try and throw some numbers up here to futher illustrate my reasoning, these are pretty rough but I hope helpful.

Assuming a 10x10 game board, there are ~200 potential moves (swapping two adjacent pieces) most of which are invalid.  Let's say there are on average 5 valid moves per "turn".  If we constrain player actions to the frame of 50 to 30,000 milliseconds, there are 149,750 potential new hashes provided the "tweaking" algorithm doesn't discard bits; I feel confident in say there are at least 10,000 potential new hashes which must be calculated by an attacker assuming a cryptographically secure hash is used.  If you throw a min-max algorithm at this, your decision tree explodes very quickly.  Throw a game session expiration at this, say 30 minutes, and I believe the attack because equivalent in complexity to writing a little bot program to play for you which cannot reasonably be defended against.

Answer (score 3):

If the client code calculates the next piece and you can't hide this algorithm very well, then some bored college student will figure this out.  As a result, they will be able to generate a massive score and defeat your intentions.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. They'll just make a program that "plays" the board with many different scenarios, and then submit the one producing the highest score.

Comment: Worse than knowing what pieces are coming up, and planning accordingly, since the next piece is a function of time between moves, they can actually choose each piece that they get.

Comment: So, maybe I'm not being clear.  The idea is that the client calculates the next pieces based on the initial seed provided by the server.  The server is confirming that the client acted in good faith based on what it posts back.

Also, hiding the algorithm is not the point.  You seem to be advocating security through obscurity, unless I miss understand.

@Lasse: The search space on that is... considerable I think.  X moves * N milliseconds per search-tree level where X is one the order of 10 and N is on the order of 10,000.

Comment: @Kevin Montrose, if the server only validates that the returned string contains a valid "game", a person only has to generate a good string of valid moves (generated with their own program) and they will get a great score.  If they take your server based seed and can generate the board and next pieces from it they can manipulate the process in any way they want.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to say that it is impossible to do. Why? You cannot trust the client - I could just analyse and completly rewrite the client side code and return whatever values I like. The only way to protect you from cheating and all kinds of attacks is to perform the logic at the server - the client will just collect user input and display the server output. But this is completly against your design goal to minimize the number of server calls.

Comment: You are correct in that the client can always return whatever it wants, but I think its possible to design a system that enforcing meaningful constraints on what the client can get the server to accept.

Comment: I think only in a very limited way. A simple model: The server sends initialization values fixing the initial layout and the sequence of pieces. The client returns a sequence of moves. Now you can validate that the sequence of moves is valid for the send initial values. But you have no control about what the client did with the initial values. I could take them and perform a search accross all possible moves to find the one with the highest score. Then I just send the best sequence with random but plausible timing values back and get my score.

Comment: Everything besides this simple model - send initial values and get list of moves back - will make it harder to cheat but nothing more. So you can hash the state, mix it with timing information, or whatever, but this will add no security at all - just take a bit longer to unterstand what's going on.

Comment: Part of the idea is to role your timing values back into the RNG, which makes the search space much larger.  I freely admit that given sufficient time anything like this can be broken (in this case, best moves chosen dishonestly), but if the time required is large enough I don't think its an issue.

Comment: Feeding the timing back will not increase the search space - it will just change the sequence of pieces. (It becomes obviouse if you imagine that you fix the times for every move - for example one every second - before you start to play. The same applies to feeding back the last move - it will change the sequence of pieces but only in different subspaces.)

Comment: Then you're not guaranteed ideal, if you fix the time interval, as it discards a large number of valid potential game "boards".  I'm beginning to think that the attack is going to be roughly equal in complexity to building a program that plays for you, using alpha-beta pruning on unknowns.  Which would be acceptable.

Comment: You are right, fixing the times will discard a lot of the search space - I missed this point. But you could still perform a randomized search on this huge search space and perform much better than a human. Using A* search might be a good way to explore the search space.

Comment: Eh, most (possibly all) of the great search algorithms rely on heuristic estimates of distance-to-goal.  Having neither the goal nor a reliable heuristic would make this problem trickier than you're making it out to be I suspect.

Regardless, can you think of an improvement to the approach that still minimizes callbacks?

Comment: I think you already got the best possible approach. It's indeed much better then I thought when I first read the question. When you got it working, I would like to try cheating...